# backend_clean_cache cron never completes

Tags: magento2, cache, magento-cron

If I run

`SELECT job_code,scheduled_at,executed_at,finished_at FROM cron_schedule where executed_at is not null and finished_at is null;`

I can see backend_clean_cache never completes

Has anyone had this issue or does anyone know how to call backend_clean_cache manually so that I can try to debug to see what it never completes

Answer (score 0):

Have this issue on 2.3.4-p2 and have tried a few suggestions. Seems it has been recognised and fixed on 2.4.1 release but doesn't help us on 2.3 with all stable extensions.

Most stable I can get it is to change the cron time (default is 2:30am) an although some jobs are missed when it executes, it doesn't get stuck every day now, just every 3rd Sunday, which is weird in itself.